# How can I make values 0 that are null on ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with null values as below. How can I convert the null values in this table to 0?

| JOBS | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | - |
| B | 15000 |
| C | - |

Comment: `coalesce(Salary, 0)`, ANSI SQL - works with any dbms!

Answer (score 2):

Use `NVL` function

```
select jobs, nvl(salary, 0) as salary
from your_table
```

Or `COALESCE`

```
select jobs, coalesce(salary, 0) as salary
from your_table
```

Or `DECODE`

```
select jobs, decode(salary, null, 0, salary) as salary
from your_table
```

Or `CASE`

```
select jobs, case when salary is null then 0 else salary end as salary
from your_table
```

---

For example (based on scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> select
  2    ename,
  3    comm,
  4    nvl(comm, 0) comm_1,
  5    coalesce(comm, 0) comm_2,
  6    decode(comm, null, 0, comm) comm_3,
  7    case when comm is null then 0 else comm end comm_4
  8  from emp;

ENAME            COMM     COMM_1     COMM_2     COMM_3     COMM_4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH                          0          0          0          0
ALLEN             300        300        300        300        300
WARD              500        500        500        500        500
JONES                          0          0          0          0
MARTIN           1400       1400       1400       1400       1400
BLAKE                          0          0          0          0
<snip>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a DDL statement to make this change permanent for the column

```
ALTER TABLE tab 
MODIFY salary DEFAULT 0;
```